# ADO.NET DateTime sql parameter lose accuracy

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, ado.net

I am trying to delete records with ADO.NET for SQL Server, of which there is a sql command with the `DateTime` type parameter.

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM [{0}] WHERE UtcTimeStamp=@UtcTimeStamp", ...);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UtcTimeStamp", DbType.DateTime2) { Value = exactTime });
    sqlConnection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I pass the `exactTime` for example `2014-12-22 04:53:21.9690398`, meanwhile I checked the database, the record with this `UtcTimeStamp` value exists, but the record would not be deleted after I execute my code.

I checked the Sql Profier, found the `UtcTimeStamp` parameter in sql command was parsed to `2014-12-22 04:53:21.970`, I think that's why my code doesn't work.

So, how can I force the parsed `UtcTimeStamp` use the exactly same accuracy with the input?

Comment: I suggest to delete record on basis of primary key of like Id. `Datetime` filed never use to delete record. It is use in case of data filter only(Reports).

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov thanks, but it is used for `Decimal` type.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov huh interesting, I was keep looking at this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale(v=vs.110).aspx, but anyway I've tried the `Scale`, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @marc_s thanks, it's `datetime2(7)` in database. The problem has been solved, please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found the point: the `SqlParameter`'s second argument is not correct, it should be

```
new SqlParameter("@UtcTimeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime2) { Value = exactTime }
```

If I pass the `DbType` into it, it will be identified by it's another constructor:

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value) : this()
{
   this.ParameterName = parameterName;
   this.Value = value;
}
```

So the `SqlDbType` property of this instance would use default `SqlDbType.DateTime`, which is not correct. Instead I should use this constructor:

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType) : this()
{
   this.ParameterName = parameterName;
   this.SqlDbType = dbType;
}
```

Comment: Why. Why. Why.   Why.     Why.   Why.. would they make the default NOT map the same precision as the .NET DateTime type.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you save this vlaue in db its type is `DbType.DateTime2` because this type rounds the value of nanoseconds with an accuracy of 100. So i think when you save this in database you are saving it as `DbType.DateTime`
make sure it is `DbType.DateTime2`.